# Validação se algum input do form foi alterado

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu preciso verificar se o form houve alguma alteração, ou seja, se foi alterado algum dado do input, etc. 
Para que quando for fazer o `submit`, ou sair da página, realizar algum click de button, ou do menu seja informado para o usuário que os dados foram alterados, e que ainda não foram salvos.
Localizei este [link](https://danielwisky.com.br/2016/02/14/jquery-alteracao-formulario/), porém não sei se é possível, eu queria que em qualquer click que não fosse o submit da página e tivesse feito a alteração o usuário fosse notificado, pra fazer isso eu tenho que chamar a `function` em vários lugares, ou existe uma função que faça isso geral na página do `form` ?

Comment: Poderia colocar ao menos um código que tenha desenvolvido?

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz em qualquer `form` eu quero fazer a validação dos `input`

Comment: Se você usar o evento `onchange` em todos os campos, ele vai dar um alerta sempre que foi modificado. Ai então você valida pra mostrar o alerta apenas se a pessoa não tiver salvo. Só que fazer da forma que você falou é bem incomodo, a não ser que ele já venha todo preenchido, afinal sempre que alguém mexer em qualquer input ele vai acusar o alerta. O ideal seria ele alertar que não foi salvo na hora do submit.

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo então e como posso fazer isso ? de uma maneira rápida, sem precisar mexer em todos os campos ?

Comment: É algo tão simples. Mas sem ver o código fica complicado de fazer um exemplo. Faça um `onsumbit`, dentro previna o submit de acontecer com o `e.preventDefault()`, verifique se tudo foi salvo (essa parte não sei como fazer sem ver como você salva). `if( /*foi salvo */ ) { form.submit() } else { alert('salve todos os campos!') }`. Se for isso mesmo que você quer e ainda assim não souber fazer, posta seu código e eu faço um exemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 $('form').on('change paste', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
    $mudou=true;
});


$( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {

if ($mudou==true){

   var msj='Algo mudou no formulário, deseja envia-lo?';
   if (!confirm(msj)) { 
      return false;
   } else {
     $( "#form_name" ).submit();
   }
}  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form_name" id="form_name">
  <input type="text" name="a" id="a" value="a" />
  <input type="text" name="b" id="b" value="b" />
  <input type="text" name="c" id="c" value="c" />
  <input type="text" name="d" id="d" value="d" />
  <input type="text" name="e" id="f" value="e" />
  <input type="text" name="f" id="e" value="" />
  <select name="two_g">
    <option value="111">111</option>
    <option value="222">222</option>
    <option value="333">333</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button id="mybutton">submit</button>
```

Comment: Dessa forma, sempre que muda ele aparece, eu só quero que apareça um alert quando ele tentar sair do form atual.

Comment: @marianac_costa não sei se entendi bem  `eu queria que em qualquer click que não fosse o submit da página e tivesse feito a alteração o usuário fosse notificado`

Comment: Por exemplo ele altera algo na descrição, e tem o botão de salvar, de voltar, e os itens de menu, etc, eu gostaria que qualquer click que não fosse no button de salvar, ele verificasse e fizesse a pergunta se gostaria de sair sem salvar.

Comment: @marianac_costa foi como eu disse, o que você está especificando não é o que você quer, ou você quer algo muito inviável. Qualquer click fora do botão de salvar significa inclusive se a pessoa clicar em outro input, ou sempre que ela preencher algum input, haja visto que vai mudar de vazio para preenchido.

Comment: @marianac_costa, editei a resposta. A gente aqui entende melhor um código bem formatado do que mil palavras!!